# Keep variable value after view change

Tags: flutter

In my application I have a need to keep the a value temporarily (until the app is closed) i.e. the variable starts at null then gets updated then the user navigates to a different view and comes back and the variable still has the updated value.

I can get the variable to update from user interaction in the child widget but I can't get it to persist when the user changes tab or pushes something on to the stack

```
 LatLng mapPosition;
  double zoomLevel;

 _updateMapState(LatLng position, double zoom) {

    setState(() {
      mapPosition = position;
      zoomLevel = zoom;
    });
  }
```

Im new to flutter and Im not entirely sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: Do you have some more code to show?
Because you mentioned 'tabs' I assume the view gets rebuild every time the user clicks another tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that the page/screen widget is holding the value, but that widget gets removed when the user switches tab.

There's a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1) on how to persist the different pages or tabs when switching them.

Basically you need to give every page a `PageStorageKey` and use a `PageStorage` widget with a `PageStorageBucket`.

This code snippet might help (copied from the article):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'first_page.dart';
import 'second_page.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarControllerState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarControllerState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarControllerState
    extends State<BottomNavigationBarController> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    FirstPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
    ),
    SecondPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),
    ),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('First Page')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list), title: Text('Second Page')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped immensely it pointed me in the right direction. This video was also useful in understanding page storage https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyLqj9L_Tck

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple ways you can do is you can make the variable global to the `main.dart` file and import this file wherever you are using that variable, but only thing is that you should make sure it is not null.

```
double zoomLevel; // in top of the main.dart
```